# Wine program list

Tags: linux, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Softwares  in Ubuntu ( Using Wine )](https://superuser.com/questions/61921/windows-softwares-in-ubuntu-using-wine)

Does anybody know a list of which windows programs wine is able to run on linux?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/61921/windows-softwares-in-ubuntu-using-wine-closed

Comment: @quackquixote that link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/). It has information on which programs have been tested under Wine, which ones worked, and which ones don't. Users submit information regarding compatibility with different versions of Wine, different versions of the program, and sometimes even tweaks to get it running in a specific environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes checkout Wine App DB.

I tried installing .net framework, no luck, I used mono instead for .net based applications.

I also use wine-doors (wine-doors.org) to install applications.